# Windows Service not able to access mapped folders

Tags: vb.net

I have a very simple VB.net Windows Service written using VS.net 2008. The program after doing several other functions writes a log in one of the network folders. The code is as shown below: If I change the path from "Y:\Activity_Log" to "C:\Activity_Log" it is working like a charm.

What is the problem if I use Y drive which is a valid one and I am able to access it from other VB.net desktop apps. Please help.

```
Dim strFile As String = "Y:\Activity_Log\" & DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") & ".txt"
        Dim fs As FileStream = Nothing
        Dim activityfolder As String = "Y:\Activity_Log"
        Dim di As System.IO.DirectoryInfo

        di = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(activityfolder)

        If (Not di.Exists) Then
            di.Create()
        End If


        If (Not File.Exists(strFile)) Then
            Try
                Dim sw1 As New StreamWriter(File.Open(strFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                sw1.WriteLine("******************************Activity Log for " & Now.Date & "*******************")
                sw1.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
                sw1.WriteLine(Remarks & " ---" & DateTime.Now)
                sw1.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        Else
            Dim sw As StreamWriter
            sw = AppendText(strFile)
            sw.WriteLine(Remarks & " ---" & DateTime.Now)
            sw.Close()

        End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start->Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services

Find Your service in the list, right click on the name, Properties

Click the Log On tab

Change from Local System account to 'This Account'

Use a user that has access to that share, start with your username/password to convince yourself that it works ;)

Click Ok, then restart the service.

Comment: Sean, Thanks for your suggestion. I did specify the login details and restarted the service. It is still not working. Not just this network folder but none. I would really appreciate if you can suggest any solution for this.

Comment: Log the exception it is throwing to the eventviewer or a file, so you can figure out why access is being denied.  I would assume it is probably just permission related.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you need to run the service under a user that has access to that drive?

maybe the generic service user doesn't have access.

Comment: Fredou, Right now the service is running on my machine. Even then it is not able to access the network drive.

Comment: The service probably runs under a different user. You will want to make sure that the permissions for the mapped drive are set up to be visible for everybody.